# Required request part is not present - Spring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, ng-file-upload

I am trying to pass the attached file information to the spring controller from agularjs controller. I am facing issues while passing the information from angularjs to spring controller, it is throwing the error on the browser console and not calling the spring controller.

Error message:

```
error
:
"Required request part 'ad' is not present"
status
:
500
```

Below is the sample code i have used in my application to send the attached files and information to the spring controller from angularjs.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="sendEmailController">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" style="align-items: left" type="button"
             ng-click="cancelModal()">Close</button>
     </div><div class="col-sm-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
                            ng-click="saveForm()">Send</button>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row" >
             <input type="email" style="alignment: right" autofocus
                    name="fromEmail" size="75" 
                    ng-model="fromEmail" required ng-trim="true"</inputtext>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <input type="email" style="alignment: right" name="ccEmail" size="75"
                    ng-model="ccEmail" ng-trim="true"></inputtext>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <input type="text" style="alignment: right" name="subject" size="75"
                    ng-model="subject"  ng-trim="true"></inputtext>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <input type="file" name="attachFile" size="60" />
        </div>
        <div class="row" >
            <label style="color: #0099ff;">Message: </label>
             <textarea rows="20" maxlength=35000
                       background-color = grey; name="message"
                       ng-model="message" >
             </textarea>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

js:

```
app.controller('sendEmailController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $uibModalInstance, MyService) {
    $scope.saveForm = function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        $scope.emailData = [
            {
                'from': $scope.fromEmail,
                'ccEmail': $scope.ccEmail,
                'subject': $scope.subject,
                'message': $scope.message,
            }];

        var json = $scope.emailData;
        console.log("JSOn String: " + JSON.stringify(json));
        formData.append("file", file);
        formData.append("ad", JSON.stringify(json));//important: convert to JSON!
        MyService.sendWithAttachments(formData).then(         // $scope.fromEmail,$scope.ccEmail,$scope.subject,$scope.fileName,$scope.fileObj,$scope.message).then(
            function (response) {
                 //response
            },
            function (errResponse) {

            }
        );
    }

});
```

MyService.js

```
 _repServiceFactory.sendWithAttachments = function (formData) {

        var myUrl = appURL + '/sendData/sendEmailsTest.form'; 
        $http({
            method: "post",
            url: myUrl,
            //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
            data: formData
            /*transformRequest: function (data, headersGetterFunction) {
                return data;
            }*/

        }).success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
}
```

Springcontroller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sendData")
public class DataController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/sendEmailsTest", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String sendEmailsTest(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("request body form data  " + file); 
//logic to get the files and the information and do accordingly..
}
}
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
     </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
    </bean>
```

Any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `500` response code from the server.
You need to add one more `RequestPart` to your spring controller method i.e. update the method definition to the following

```
String sendEmailsTest(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("ad") String jsonAd) throws Exception {

}
```

You can also bind `ad` to a `Class` instead of a `String`. I have done something similar [here](https://github.com/Girija-Shankar-Swain/file-upload-ajax-sample).

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but now it is showing the error error
 Required request part 'file' is not present" status :500..I think i need to pass two arguments from MyService.js, in MyService.js i'm passing only one argument as part of data (i.e.,data: formData) .Is that the cause of issue.Any inputs would be helpful.@GSSwain

Comment: can you debug saveForm method to see if file has some value. Your html form does not seem to bind the file field. Else you can check the request payload in the network tab too. Get a handle to the file input field and append <fileInputField>.files[0] to the formData.